# Aiming for the 24

Tags: no-computers, calculation-puzzle

**6** **1** **3** **4** **=** **??**

Using four basic math signs (+, -, *, /) and brackets, for instance:

> 6 * (1 + 3) - 4 = 20
>
> 6 * 1 * 3 + 4 = 22
>
> 6 + 13 + 4 = 23
>
> (6 + 1)* 3 + 4 = 25
>
> 61 - 34 = 27

Try to achieve **24**.

Comment: This question is not made by me, I heard it from a fellow train traveller years ago, so it might be a repeat. Also: No Computers You Tricky Person!

Comment: Just noticed that $61-34=43-16$... odd coincidence?

Comment: Can we shuffle the digits?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket No, we can't.

Comment: Can we use exponentiation?

Comment: @user477343 Nope.

Comment: i start to believe that this kind of question is a duplicate of others since not much changes after another at all!

Comment: @Oray Neither the question, nor the idea of the answer corresponds that of the 2-0-1-8 question.

Comment: in my opinion, the idea is the same, there is no originality or anything that adds up this kind of questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make 10 out of 1, 1, 5 and 8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52507/make-10-out-of-1-1-5-and-8) – it's my bonus puzzle there.

Comment: @user477343 not really, because 1+6=3+4. E.g. 71-35=53-17.

Comment: @Glorfindel and $7+1=3+5$... hmmm.... interesting ;)

Comment: @Glorfindel That's more like it. You stated it as a hint, though. I'm not an expert on this site rules, but I be okay if they redirect this puzzle to yours.

Comment: In questions like these, is the `//` operator accepted?  It's just a combination of the `/` operation after all.  In that case, `61 // 3 + 4` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible solution is

> $24 = \frac{6}{1 - \frac{3}{4}}$

In the original notation

> 6/(1-(3/4)) = 24

Comment: Please rewrite it with signs and brackets, as in the problem definition. Will accept as a correct answer after then.

Comment: @ThomasBlue  Okay, no problem

Comment: You got it before me. $(+1)$ :)